# Photos app crashes when opened

Tags: windows-10-mobile, photos, system-apps, lumia-640, crash

I have a Lumia 640 with Windows 10 Mobile. Lately the Photos app, when clicked to open, just closes immediately. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Mobile has a nifty functionality that allows you to reset an app if it misbehaves. However, it is not available for most system apps, including Photos.

Try doing a **soft reset**. It usually resolves most app crash issues.

Whilst your phone is on:

> Press and hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the same time until you feel a vibration (about 10–15 seconds). Ignore the "slide down to power off" screen.